# How do i debug CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function in .Net using visual studio?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sqlclr

I have one project inside that I have `SqlServerFunctions` in test.cs file.
code:

```
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlDecimal CalculateBondDV0N(SqlDecimal coupon, SqlDecimal yield, SqlDateTime date)
    {
        DayCount dayCount = (DayCount)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayCount), dayCountString.ToString(), true);
        Frequency frequency = (Frequency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Frequency), frequencyString.ToString(), true);

        double price = BondAnalyticsUtility.CalculateDV0N((double)coupon.Value, dayCount, frequency, (double)yield.Value, date.Value, finalPaymentDate.Value, (double)redemptionValue.Value, (double)notional.Value, (double)spreadChange.Value);

        SqlDecimal returnVal = new SqlDecimal(price);

        return returnVal;
    }
```

And this function get called from Sql Server inside Scalar valued function by giving `EXTERNAL` parameter.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateBondDV0N](@Coupon [decimal](18, 6), @Yield [decimal](18, 6), @Date [datetime])
RETURNS [decimal](18, 7) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Pearl.Analytics.Services.Database].[BondAnalytics].[CalculateBondDV0N]
```

I want to debug this function the code is in c# trying to debug in into VS2010 pro
how can i attached it with database and do this.?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't need to debug it within SQL Server, then it's quite easy to just call it naturally from normal C# code. Seeing as your method only makes use of very basic types, I can't see any reason to need to debug it within SQL Server.

I am not sure where 'dayCountString' and 'frequencyString' come from, however. I have a suspicion that those should be parameters to the function too.

Comment: all the parameters to that method is selected from SQL tables so when i call any method in c# parameters are coming from SQL table

Comment: So, call it from C# with the same parameters?